# Android SDK Tools: Not compatible with Other

Tags: android

Just download latest Android SDK version from Android developers site, run ./android tool (i use Mac OS X 10.7.5) and i got next error:

*Android SDK Tools: Not compatible with Other*

http://qblx.co/ZCrpcI

So, what does it mean? What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue, it was Java 1.7 preferences, just removed Java 1.7, here are 2 links about this issue:

http://dhruba.name/2012/08/20/adding-a-jdk-and-sources-to-eclipse-on-a-mac/
http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/10/31/no-more-java-preferences-for-you/

Comment: Accept your own answer, maybe giving more details for others.

Answer (score 1):

Never saw that. Better uninstall and reinstall everything. Clean up (rm -rf) the android sdk folder and reinstall.

Comment: Did you really wipe out the android-sdk folder ?

Comment: is there any .android folder left in your personal folder after uninstalling. (Please do this via command line, not via the finder).

Comment: removed... but issue still exist :(

Comment: Is there any thing left to read, I mean if you expand the column ?